# jquery .when function not trigger

Tags: jquery, function, promise, deferred, .when

In the following function, the $.when() never triggers. It goes right to the .then().

None of the console.log statements within that function fire, nor does the ajax query when it meets the criteria that would trigger the ajax

Why?

```
$(`#btnUpdatePrice`).on(`click`, function() {
    console.log(`updating stuff`);
    curCell.attr(`spactualprice`, $(`#priceModalNewPrice`).val());// - ($(`#priceModalNewPrice`).val() * discountRate));
    curCell.attr(`personalizationQuantity`, $(`#tbPersonalization`).val());
    const dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.when(function() {
        console.log(`starting function: `, $(`#QtyM186610`).length);
        if ($(`#QtyM186610`).length) {
            const tval = +$(`#QtyM186610`).val() + (+$(`#tbPersonalization`).val());
            console.log(`personalization item already exists: `, tval);
            $(`#QtyM186610`).val(tval);
            return dfd.resolve();
        } else {
            return $.ajax({
                url: `KP_AdminEditOrder_Ajax.asp`,
                type: `POST`,
                data: {prodList: `186610`, action: `addProducts`, ATBPricing: objCustomer.ATBPricing, custType: objCustomer.customerType, orderId: objOrder.idOrder},
                beforeSend: function() {
                },
            }).done(function(data) {
                const results = parseReturn(data);
                const tProds = results.ProductInfo;
                const firstProd = tProds[0].parentProd;
                curParentProduct = -1;
                objProducts = objProducts.concat(tProds);
                objProducts.forEach((product) => {
                    if (product.orginalProd === -1) return;
                    displayProduct(product, true);
                });
                totalQuant = 0;
                totalPrice = 0;
                totalRowQuant = 0;
                totalRowPrice = 0;
                curParentProduct = -1;
                $(`html, body`).scrollTop($(`[idparentprd="${firstProd}"]`).offset().top);
                $(`#QtyM186610`).val($(`#tbPersonalization`).val());
            }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            });
        }
    }).then(function() {
        console.log(`recalc from price update`);
        recalcRow(curCell);
    });
    curCell=``;
});
```

Comment: The argument to `$.when()` should be a `Deferred`, not a function.

Comment: Yup. As soon as I moved it to a discrete function and called it with $.when(), it worked perfectly.

thank you. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?